# You can modify user data with chfn (e.g. phone, room) but how can you just display that organisational data?

Tags: users, user-management, adduser

Edit:
@steeldriver provided the answer I believe.
I think I found the reason why I did not get the output that I wanted in the first place. When I created the user I entered Full Name, Room Number, Work Phone, Home Phone and Other. But I overlooked an error message. Even though the organisational information (aka GECOS information as @muru made me aware of) is missing the user was created successfully it seems. The error message read:

```
chfn: fields too long
adduser: `/bin/chfn user_that_i_created' returned error code 1. Exiting.
```

End of edit.

Sorry for asking this, I really tried to find the answer myself and I seem to be unable to ask Google the right question to find the answer I need.

Ok, so we all know how to find user data which is interesting from a technical point of view, using `/etc/passwd` and `grep` or other commands. But this is not what I am looking for.

When you create a user, you are asked for room, work phone and other organisational data. You would change that data with `chfn`. But how can you just output that data? It must be in some file I guess? Can I do `cat [file where organisational user data is stored]` to see the phone number, room number, etc? How can I display that information?

Comment: Are you talking about GECOS information? That's stored in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fn` in `chfn` stands for **f**ull**n**ame, and the information is stored in the fullname field of the password database - or what `man 5 passwd` calls the

> ```
> ·   user name or comment field
> ```

(it's also commonly referred to as the [GECOS field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field)). So you can retrieve it using `getent`

```
$ getent passwd testuser
testuser:x:1001:1001:John Doe,101,234-555-1224,689-555-3785:/home/testuser:/bin/sh
```

If you're using local account management (rather than some kind of distributed management such as NIS or LDAP), the data is stored as plain text in the `/etc/passwd` file, and may be accessed directly with `cat` or `less` or with any of the various text processing tools ex.

```
$ awk -F: -v user=testuser '$1 == user {print $5}' /etc/passwd
John Doe,101,234-555-1224,689-555-3785
```

You can also use the `finger` command to access it in human readable format:

```
$ finger -l testuser
Login: testuser                         Name: John Doe
Directory: /home/testuser               Shell: /bin/sh
Office: 101, 234-555-1224               Home Phone: 689-555-3785
Last login Thu Jul  8 14:41 (EDT) on pts/2 from 192.168.1.4
No mail.
No Plan.
```

Comment: WOW!  I was just going to write about the `getent` command.  Nice answer!  +1  However, finger is not installed by default.  :(  But I definitely like the output of `finger` a lot more than `getent`.  :)

Comment: @Terrance maybe the awked version is cleaner? that could be applied to the `getent` version as well of course

Comment: Yeah, the `awk` version is a lot cleaner.  You have given me some really good ideas on what to do with my team info here in my own office (well, really I work from home still but I have been looking for more ways to store tech info and locations).  You have helped me TONS even though I am not the OP of the question.  :)

Comment: In the old times of the Internet ;), `finger` was commonly used to obtain information about remote users, you could just type `finger user@server.dom.ain` to get the info about user of almost any server. As far as I know, the GECOS field was meant specifically to be used with `finger` command.